# Symfony2: Setting entity value from parent

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FoSUserBundle. I Have a User entity. I need to set code property with the username during registration. How can i do this.

```
protected $code = parent::username;
```

Is this correct? I don't know much of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be creating `@PrePersist` callback if I understand your problem correctly. E.g

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCodeValue() 
    {
        $this->code = $this->username;
    }
}
```

For more info check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks).